# Google signOut issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been creating a login app that has function of registration and log in with gmail account.
the issue is whenever I sign its the account  the account automatically gets signed in with the first account and its unable to sign out.
and in firebase the userid is show which isnt logged in.
Every time the same account is getting signed it.

here is my profile activity.
after the user gets signed in the profile activity opens.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    profiletx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext);
    user=auth.getCurrentUser();
    profiletx.setText(user.getEmail());
    signout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signout);

}
 public void signOut(View v)
{
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    auth.signOut();
    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);

}
```

this is my LOginActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googleid);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SignIn();

        }
    });

}
private void SignIn()
{
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);

            // ...
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("Login", "signInWithCredential:success");
                        user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully signed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unsuccessfully sign", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);

                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}
private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
    if (acct != null) {
        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
        String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
        String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
        String personId = acct.getId();
        Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
    }
}


    public void Signin(View v)
    {
        if (e1.getText().toString().equals("") && e2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter the details please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(e1.getText().toString(), e2.getText().toString())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "could not logiged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to log out of GoogleSignInClient as well , for example on button click :

```
public void signOut() {
signOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
       GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getContext(), gso);
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class));
    }
});
```

}

Comment: nope bro still the same issue..the user isnt getting logged out.i have two activities one is for login purposes and another is for profile were i mentioned signout option for the user to get signout and return to main activity.

Comment: yes bro, i have updated the loginactivity, please check it